# How do I collapse a navbar for mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

```css
.navbar {
 background:white;
 border: 1px solid #008080;
 border-width: 1px 0;
  box-shadow: 0px -4px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75), 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}

.navbar-contact,
.nav {
 background: #008080;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar-contact {
 max-height: 29px;
}

.bottom {
 margin-top: -30px;
}

/* White Angles (Common) */

.nav:before,
.navbar-contact:after {
 content: "";
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 2em; height: 4em;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}

/* .navbar-contact angle position */

.navbar-contact:after {
    right: -1em;
    top: -0.5em;
}

/* .nav angle position */

.nav:before {
    left: -1em;
    top: -1em;
}
.head-text{
 padding-top:1px;
 font-family:Righteous;
 text-align:center;
 color:#78ece9;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link href="http://computervision.in/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://computervision.in/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
<body id="top">
<nav class="navbar p-0 fixed-top">
   <div class="top d-flex w-100">
     <div class="px-2 navbar-contact text-white position-relative flex-grow-1">Contact: <a class="text-white" href="#">+91 xxxxxxxxxx or + 91 xxxxxxxxxx </a></div>
       <div class="pt-1 pr-3 d-flex mt-auto bg-white position-relative">
                 <div class="dropdown">
         <img class="position-relative" src="http://computervision.in/images/IN.png" height="50">
                      <div class="dropdown-content2">
                                <a class="my-font" href="courses.php">Courses</a>
                                <a class="my-font" href="login.php">Student Login</a>
                                <a class="my-font" href="#">Make Payments</a>
                                <a class="my-font" href="#">Student Review</a>
                                <a class="my-font" href="#">Verify Certificates</a>
                                <a class="my-font" href="#">Online Registration</a>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <img class="position-relative ml-3 mr-2" src="http://computervision.in/images/PV.png" height="55">
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a class="my-font" href="#">Gallery</a>
                            <a class="my-font" href="#">Hot Jobs</a>
                            <a class="my-font" href="#">Placement Cell</a>
                            <a class="my-font" href="#">Top Placements</a>
                            <a class="my-font" href="#">Placement Drive</a>
                            <a class="my-font" href="placement.php">Placement Testimonials</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
       </div>
      </div>
                <div class="bottom d-flex w-100">
                <div class="navbar-brand">
                <a class="navbar-brand mr-0" href="#"> <img src="http://computervision.in/images/logo.png" height="60"> </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" id="nav1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navMain" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
                    </div>
                    
                 <ul class="nav mt-auto flex-grow-1 pl-4 position-relative" role="navigation" id="navMain">
                     <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link my-font" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link my-font" href="about.php">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link my-font" href="why.php">Why Computer Vision</a></li> 
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link my-font" href="courses.php">Courses</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link my-font" href="services.php">Services</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link my-font" href="events.php">Events</a></li>
                         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link my-font" href="blogs.php">Blogs</a></li>
                          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link my-font blink" href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link my-font" href="register.php">Register</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 
                    
            </div>
  </nav>
<!-- Contact Us Section -->
   
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried a lot of codes for [This Code](https://jsfiddle.net/0m9ofvcg/) in order to make it responsive in mobile devices, so that when a user accesses my page from mobile he gets a collapsed navigation bar. I have tried in every way, the `navbar collapse` class doesn't even seem to work. so I have removed the whole code for collapsing the navbar. Please help me out, i've been stuck in here for many days. Thanks anyways.

Comment: include your code in the post please

Comment: May be because of viewport metadata is missing, Add below viewport metadata in head tag and try.
"<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">"

Comment: i've tried it as well. please check @Vikrant

Comment: @xmastertje I've posted the snippet on the post. please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.navbar {
 border: 1px solid #008080;
 border-width: 1px 0;
  box-shadow: 0px -4px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75), 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}

.navbar-contact,
.nav, .navbar-nav {
 background: #008080;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar-contact {
 max-height: 29px;
}

.bottom {
 margin-top: -30px;
}

/* White Angles (Common) */

.nav:before,
.navbar-contact:after {
 content: "";
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 2em; height: 2.5em;
    transform: skew(-30deg);
}

/* .navbar-contact angle position */

.navbar-contact:after {
    right: -1em;
    top: 0;
}

/* .nav angle position */

.nav:before {
    left: -1em;
    top: 0;
}

.navbar.navbar-expand-lg {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.navbar-toggler {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
.navbar .bottom.d-flex {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.navbar-toggler-icon {
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg viewBox='0 0 30 30' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path stroke='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/></svg>");
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
 </head>

 <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg p-0">
   <div class="top d-flex w-100">
     <div class="px-2 navbar-contact text-white position-relative flex-grow-1">Contact: <a class="text-white" href="#">+91 xxxxxxxxxx or xxxxxxxxxx </a></div>
       <div class="pt-1 pr-3 d-flex mt-auto bg-white position-relative">
        <img class="position-relative" src="http://computervision.in/images/IN.png" height="50">
        <img class="position-relative ml-3 mr-2" src="http://computervision.in/images/PV.png" height="55">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom d-flex w-100">
          <a href="" class="navbar-brand mr-0">
                <img src="http://computervision.in/images/logo.png" height="60">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1 pl-4 position-relative">
                        <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link text-white active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Courses</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Events</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Blogs</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
      </div>
        </nav>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </body>

</html>
```

```
You just have to modify CSS as per your design. Hope this will work for you.
```

Comment: please include the code directly in the answer and explain why this should fix OP's issue

Comment: finally, after a long hardwork... it worked. Thanks for the lead @Vikrant.

Comment: Thank you all, for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

here is small example for a collapsing navbar. Please give it a try. Run the snippet in the post and fullscreen to see how it works.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: it's there in my original code, it still doesn't work. would you please try out the JSFiddle and do some magic on it ;)

Comment: There is a problem with your custom Css @WillsonMarandi you set some absolute variables which causes the issue. Please start from scratch with my answer and reduce the custom css to a minimum. :)